# PHP Redirect Pause

Tags: php, redirect

How do I pause a page for a certain amount of seconds before redirecting the user to another HTML/PHP page using PHP?

Comment: I never understood why I have to wait x number of seconds so they can redirect me to another page why would I do that?

Comment: Becose some browser - or browser's settings - wont let the redirect... and showing a intermediate-page is clearly for the user then multiple-loading page without understand what is happening.. the X (usually 5) seconds are there to let the user read the message ;)

Comment: @Thomaschaaf: There is a few reasons possible, a) because they don't realize there is no need, b) advertising, while the user 'waits' they might see an add and click, c) conformity, everyone does it so everyone expects an intermittent page (ie my boss made me implement one, even though our site doesn't generate advertising revenue just because he was used to seeing it and thought our users would also.)

Answer (score 39):

This one should works:

```
<?php
header('Refresh: 5; URL=http://yoursite.com/page.php');
//other code
?>
```

and will allow your user to see whatever kind of output you want (You'll be redirected in X Seconds, click yere if dont, etc..)

Comment: I actually like this solution much better than what I posted. +1

Comment: really? i tested on chrome, ff, ie, opera and safari, all on windows environment, and all works as the same.
On what OS did you try it?
Couldnt be any kind of browser's setting?

Answer (score 18):

Low-tech solution requiring no Javascript or even PHP:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Redirecting...</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" 
content="10;URL=http://www.newsite.com">
</head>
<body>
    You are being automatically redirected to a new location.<br />
    If your browser does not redirect you in 10 seconds, or you do
    not wish to wait, <a href="http://www.newsite.com">click here</a>. 
</body>
</html>
```

The advantage of this solution over using the "Location:" header is that you don't need to pause the script execution, which will appear to the user as if the server is busy or their connection has hung.

This solution also gives the user the option of proceeding to the new page immediately rather than having to wait *x number of seconds* while their browser displays no information.

Edit: I think it's also worth noting that if you do decide to use the the header() method, you need to make sure your sleep() duration isn't too long. I think most browsers generate a *connection timed out* after not receiving any data from the server for 1 minute.

Comment: Be carefully - some browser (like chrome and opera) won't take this way correctly

Comment: Really? I did not know that. Well, at least they have the link to click on then.

Comment: Yes, i dont remember exacly if the browser who didnt handle it properly are safari, opera or chrome.. i remember that as 2 of them.... but maybe they fixed this issue in the time

Comment: Wait, all! Just tested this way with: ff, safari, chrome, opera and IE.. all of them handle it correctly.
I'm sure that just une years ago two of them didn't, but now seem resolved.

Comment: 'meta' tags with 'http-equiv' attribute are an alternative to HTTP headers, so you can also use 'Refresh:' header as DaNieL answered below.

Answer (score 8):

**never** use sleep this way.
Even under slight load your server will run out of http connections. Worst if your firewall runs out.

The delay parameter in the redirect header is made for exactly to the same reason.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to wait and then go back to the previous page here's how

```
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 

header ("Refresh: 2;URL='$referrer'");
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: this works, but may not be the most appropriate solution for this situation. See comments.

Might this be what you are looking for?

```
<?php
sleep(5);
header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
exit();
?>
```

Comment: Does this really work?
I thought that with the sleep function the browser just keep'n'load the page for (in your example) 5 seconds.. but without throw out the output

Comment: @DaNieL I haven't tested this, so you may be correct that it does or does not work depending on server settings or the time / place that you call this code.

Comment: I've just tested, it works, but prevent all the others output too.. afaik the sleep sleep() funcion keep in pause the entire php render, so imho shouldn't be used for this kind of issues

Comment: You should put a call to flush() before sleep() to send whatever has been output to the browser.

Comment: @OllieSaunders If you call flush() you cannot change headers than. It will not work. HTTP headers are sent before the content!

Answer (score 3):

The other 2 options are a Javascript redirect using setTimeout() or a meta refresh tag with a timeout.

Answer (score 1):

put this in the header.

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0.01;makensucces.html" />
```

on the place 0.01 you must put the seconds, i have used an decimal number.

and on the place of makensucces.html you need to put the name off the file you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php
$url=base_url().'page_you_want_to_go_to'
header('Refresh: X; URL=$url');
?>
```

This will give you additional flexibility when exchanging between localhost and remote server.