# execute php program after some second

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have a url shortner script. There is a 'forward.php' file which is used to redirect the queries if it is shortened. But in this file i want to show some text or ads for 5-10 seconds before redirecting it to the original url.

I also try sleep(), flush() and all and nothing help.

Thank you.

Code:

```
    <?php
    ob_start();
    require("lib/config.php");
    require("lib/common.php");
    if( isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ){
        $i = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    }else{
        $i = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $i = str_replace("/","",$i);
    }
    $suffix = $i{0};
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id,url FROM urls WHERE short_url = '$i'",DBH) or die(mysql_error());  
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $id = $row['id'];
        $url = $row['url'];
        mysql_query("UPDATE urls SET hits=hits+1 WHERE id = '{$id}'",DBH);

    if  ($_SESSION['config']['bar'] == true) 
    {   

$meela_urllow = stripslashes(str_replace(",", "%2C", $url));
$meela_urllow = strtolower($meela_urllow);
if ((strpos($meela_urllow, "youtube")))
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header("Location: ".stripslashes(str_replace(",", "%2C", $url)));
}

if ((strpos($meela_urllow, "facebook")))
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header("Location: ".stripslashes(str_replace(",", "%2C", $url)));
}

if ((strpos($meela_urllow, "google")))
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header("Location: ".stripslashes(str_replace(",", "%2C", $url)));
}


    } else {
        header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
        header("Location: ".stripslashes(str_replace(",", "%2C", $url)));
    }


        exit;
    }

    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header("Location: http://".$_SESSION['config']['domain']);
    exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `header()` function with refresh value if you want do display text before redirect:

```
header('Refresh: 5; url=some_url.php'); // tell browser to wait 5 sec then redirect
```

sleeping a php script is same as pausing it... script will just hang and do nothing, using output buffers cannot help since `Location` header must be sent before any HTTP body is sent, so only option is using a header Refresh.

This is the same as using `header()` function but php code is not needed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/737003/555097

Comment: but i am unable to use,

stripslashes(str_replace(",", "%2C", $url))

with header refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use javascript to do thi task for you!
just a js script that waits for 5 seconds once page loads and then redirect

```
<script>
setTimeout("redir()",5000);
function redir()
{
   window.location.href = 'your url here';
}
</script>
```